# Between AudioTrack.write and AudioFlinger.read

Tags: android, pcm, audiotrack, audioflinger

I am checking the possibility of this way, if I got any silly thinking, please correct me.
I would like to enhance the audio quality. According to some knowledge from web, I found that When an `audio/music/sound` is played , the `AudioTrack` will `write()` PCM data to the sharedbuffer, and then `AudioFlinger` will `read()` the PCM data form this sharedbuffer.
The idea is to use a service to intercept the PCM data after it is wrote by `AudioTrack.write()`, modify the PCM data, and then restore it back to the sharedbuffer for `AudioFlinger` to `read()`;
Could anyone help/correct me, please?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know much about AudioFlinger, but to read the PCM data you can make use of AudioRecord and to write the PCM data you can use AUdioTrack to play the sound.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But I am not intent to playback/record the music, the PCM data from AudioTrack is then immediately forward to the speaker. Your suggestion is still much appreciated !!